# Counting multiple checkboxes on a form, enabling a button

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have tried at least a dozen different codes to get this to work with no avail. I have a dynamic HTML form that asks the student to select which of the 10 prerequisites they have completed. Once they select at least 3, I want a Continue button to enable. The button triggers another function so they can continue with the form. I cannot get the button to enable. I am trying to stick with Javascript exclusively since I am not sure that our website has JQuery libraries available. Our web server is Cascade CMS v8.0.2 (176cf).

Below is a copy of the specific code and HTML for this section of the form. Everything else on the form functions as I expect. Any help as to why this might not be working would be greatly appreciated.

In the actual form I use a *style="display: none;"* in the *div id="blkPreReq"* tag to only display when certain criteria are met

```js
function numberOfCheckboxesSelected() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name="PreReq[]"]:checked').length;
}

function onChange() {
  document.getElementById('blkCountBtn').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('btnCountBtn').disabled = numberOfCheckboxesSelected() < 3;
}

document.getElementById('ApptInfo').
addEventListener('change', onChange, false);
```

```html
<form id="ApptInfo">
<div id="blkPreReq">
  <fieldset id="lblPreReq">
    <legend>Please indicate the prerequisites you have completed?*</legend>
    <input id="PreReqBio" name="PreReq[]" type="checkbox" value="Biology" />
    <label for="PreReqBio">Principles of Biology</label>
    <br />
    <input id="PreReqHA" name="PreReq[]" type="checkbox" value="Anatomy" />
    <label for="PreReqHA">Human Anatomy</label>
    <br />
    <input id="PreReqHP" name="PreReq[]" type="checkbox" value="Physiology" />
    <label for="PreReqHP">Human Physiology</label>
    <br />
    <input id="PreReqChem" name="PreReq[]" type="checkbox" value="Chemistry" />
    <label for="PreReqChem">Elementary Chemistry</label>
    <br />
    <input id="PreReqBioOrg" name="PreReq[]" type="checkbox" value="Bio-Organic" />
    <label for="PreReqBioOrg">Elementary Bio-Organic Chemistry</label>
    <br />
    <input id="PreReqStats" name="PreReq[]" type="checkbox" value="Statistics" />
    <label for="PreReqStats">Introduction to Statistical Inference</label>
    <br />
    <input id="PreReqNutr" name="PreReq[]" type="checkbox" value="Nutrition" />
    <label for="PreReqNutr">Nutrition Intervention</label>
    <br />
    <input id="PreReqDev" name="PreReq[]" type="checkbox" value="Development" />
    <label for="PreReqDev">Human Development: Lifespan</label>
    <br />
    <input id="PreReqMicro" name="PreReq[]" type="checkbox" value="Microbiology" />
    <label for="PreReqMicro">Medical Microbiology</label>
    <br />
    <input id="PreReqPatho" name="PreReq[]" type="checkbox" value="Pathophysiology" />
    <label for="PreReqPatho">Pathophysiology</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="blkCountBtn" style="display: none;">
  <button disabled="disabled" id="btnCountBtn" name="CountBtn" onclick="NextProgram()" type="button">Continue</button>
</div></form>
```

Comment: works for me. Where is the problem?

Comment: What doesn't work on your code snippet ? If I check 3 checkboxes, button is enabled

Comment: works for me too. 3 checkboxes selected =  button enabled

Comment: IE11, Chrome, Firefox... all working.

Comment: That's so weird. The button will not enable for me on my website. :-/ Ok well at least I know the code works. I will keep playing with it on my end.

Comment: for god's sake, use [jquery](http://jquery.com)!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r09cane4/ works fine.

Comment: Try fixing the indentation, and check if the new-lines are right.